# Sql - split recurrring row values into new columns

Tags: sql

I have a query which lists the cities of the same name that occur in different states

```
+----------+-------+
| city     | state |
+----------+-------+
| x        | melb  | 
| x        | syd   | 
| y        | bris  | 
| y        | ACT   | 
+----------+-------+
```

i wantr to format such as this

```
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| city1    | state1|city2   |state2  |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| x        | melb  | x      | syd    |
| y        | bris  | y      | ACT    |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want pairs, then use a self join:

```
select c1.city, c1.state, c2.state
from cities c1 join
     cities c2
     on c1.city = c2.city and c1.state < c2.state;
```

But that is unsatisfying.  I would rather see all states for a given city on one row.  For this, string aggregation can be used -- the specific functions differ by database.  But the SQL standard specifies `listagg()`:

```
select city, listagg(state, ', ') within group (order by state)
from cities
group by city;
```

Comment: so to create the table i join 2 other tables to have all the relevant data, am i able to self join a table that has been created by an inner join in the same query?

Comment: @shitathakin . . . Just use a CTE.  However, I note that you asked another question, where I show how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your dbms it's difficult to suggest a better solution.
If you have only two states for a city then please check it out:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table mytable (city     varchar(10), state varchar(50));
 insert into mytable values ('x','melb');
 insert into mytable values ('x','syd');
 insert into mytable values ('y','bris');
 insert into mytable values ('y','ACT');
```

Query:

```
 select city city1,max(state) State1,city city2,min(state)state2 from mytable
 group by city
```

Output:

| city1 | State1 | city2 | state2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | syd | x | melb |
| y | bris | y | ACT |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27ce68a65ab79e3c3452f7f49a517a98)*

Answer (score -1):

I think we could user inner query to separate the original table into 2 tables: (city1, state 1) and (city2, state 2) , with condition as city 1 = city 2, state 1 <> state 2. And then join them together

Comment: Hello @Hoainguyen.  Please don't use the Answer facility to give opinions on things that might work.  The purpose of the Answer facility, is to give specific and clear instruction that will put the poster close to a solution.